# Data erased from Sqlite db when moving from page to another

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

I use phonegap to build applications for Android & IOS.
I store my database using sqlite. 
I have a main javascript file in which the initialization of the DB & the main functions are written, then at the other pages I put the database functions related to that page.

The problem is that when I make some operations on the DB from another page then move to the next page & retrieve the data, I find that all what I made before was erased and it just brings the data from the main javascript file.

I'm wondering how can I let the data be saved & prevent it from being deleted whenever I move from one page to another.

The main javascript file that I use at all the pages contains this for the db initialization:

```
function populateDB(tx) {
tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table');
}
```

Is this the problem ? Should I stop the table from being dropped every time I use the db.
But If I removed it, what should I make at the very first time while creating the DB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you every time drop the table so when you move on next page you lost the data from previous page. you should make very first time creating db table like below.

```
function populateDB(tx) { 
tx.executeSql('create table if not exists TableName (id integer)'); 
}
```